# Need regular expression for validating date in dd-MMM-yyyy format

Tags: asp.net, regex

I am not expert in writing regular expressions so need your help. I want to validate date in "dd-MMM-yyyy" format i.e. 07-Jun-2012. I am using RegularExpressionValidator in asp.net.

Can anybody help me out providing the expression?

Thanks for sharing your time.

Comment: Where is the data coming from - if user entry surely better to use a Date field to fully validate it -as a regex won't capture correct 29th Feb etc

Comment: Do you just want syntactically valid dates or do you want actual valid dates? For example, should the regex reject 30-Feb-2012 because it's an impossible date?

Comment: I just need syntactically valid dates, although it would be better if regex completely validates it.

Comment: I am using textbox with jquery datepicker to get date.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/3858413/121309

Comment: Did you check the related questions section? ----v

Comment: [this link should help you at all...](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using a DatePicker is probably the best approach.  However, since that's not what you asked, here's an option (although it's case sensitive):

```
^(([0-9])|([0-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))\-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\-\d{4}$
```

In addition, here's a place you can easily test Regular Expressions:  http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Comment: nice to see link to test Regular Expressions

Comment: Hi mark, The above expression is pretty cool , I have to search and match for 1st january 2018 , I mean when we have ST , ND, NTH or TH with days of month

Answer (score 12):

Regex without leading zero in day.

```
^\d{1,2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-\d{4}$
```

**Update** Regex with leading zero in day.

```
^\d{2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-\d{4}$
```

Comment: `\d` means any digit, so the first one accepts '0' and '88' as day. Also `[a-zA-Z]{3}` matches "xYz".

Answer (score 3):

It's not regex, but you can use build in [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) function to validate your datetime string

```
DateTime dateTime;
string toValidate = "01-Feb-2000";

bool isStringValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(
    toValidate,
    "dd-MMM-yyyy",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.None,
    out dateTime);
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted solution allows '00' as the day, so here is a fix for that:

```
^(([1-9])|([0][1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))\-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\-\d{4}$
```

Notes/Exceptions:

1.Be aware of case sensitivity issues. Eg. 'DEC' will not pass while 'Dec' will pass. You may want to convert the regex string and test string to lowercase before testing (if your application allows).

2.This will not catch days that don't exist, like Feb 30th, June 31st, etc.

Comment: Can I search for 1st . 2nd , 4th, 3rd for days of month as well ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean @JotDhaliwal

Answer (score 2):

```
"\d{4}\d{2}\d{2}|\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}|\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}|\d{2}\-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)|(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\d{2}\-\d{4}|\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"
```

These format is `mm.dd.yyyy`, `d-MMM`, `mm.dd.yyyy`

Answer (score 0):

Yet another idea would be to try this (similar to user1441894's idea):

```
var x = DateTime.Parse("30-Feb").GetDateTimeFormats();
```

I learned to use this yesterday (for a different purpose). So try-catch this statement to deal with validity/invalidity of the date :)

Answer (score 0):

```
"^(([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[1-9]|3[0-1])[-]([JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JULY|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC])[-](d{4}))$"
```

Comment: Including brief about the code/solution would make this answer a complete one!

Answer (score -1):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions

private void fnValidateDateFormat(string strStartDate,string strEndDate)
{
    Regex regexDt = new Regex("(^(((([1-9])|([0][1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(30))\\-([A,a][P,p][R,r]|[J,j][U,u][N,n]|[S,s][E,e][P,p]|[N,n][O,o][V,v]))|((([1-9])|([0][1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))\\-([J,j][A,a][N,n]|[M,m][A,a][R,r]|[M,m][A,a][Y,y]|[J,j][U,u][L,l]|[A,a][U,u][G,g]|[O,o][C,c][T,t]|[D,d][E,e][C,c])))\\-[0-9]{4}$)|(^(([1-9])|([0][1-9])|([1][0-9])|([2][0-8]))\\-([F,f][E,e][B,b])\\-[0-9]{2}(([02468][1235679])|([13579][01345789]))$)|(^(([1-9])|([0][1-9])|([1][0-9])|([2][0-9]))\\-([F,f][E,e][B,b])\\-[0-9]{2}(([02468][048])|([13579][26]))$)");

    Match mtStartDt = Regex.Match(strStartDate,regexDt.ToString());
    Match mtEndDt   = Regex.Match(strEndDate,regexDt.ToString());
    if (mtStartDt.Success && mtEndDt.Success)
    {
            //piece of code
    }
}
```